# d.ts declaration for overridden class methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I'm trying to write a js file that is annotated by a d.ts file. In one of the js files I have a class that extends another class and it overrides and overloads a function from its parents like the code shown below:
test.js

```js
// @ts-check

class Test {
  constructor() {}
  foo() {}
}

class TestChild extends Test {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  foo(param1, param2) {
    return param1 + param2;
  }
}
```

dist/test.d.ts

```js
declare class Test {
    foo(): void;
}
declare class TestChild extends Test {
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/*.js"
  ]
}
```

Apparently the generated d.ts file doesn't not have declaration for the overridden foo function. What can I do to make typescript automatically generate the declaration for any function that is inherited and overridden?

Comment: Are you not getting this error - error TS2416: Property 'foo' in type 'TestChild' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Test'.
  Type '(param1: any, param2: any) => any' is not assignable to type '() => void'.?

Comment: @MBB hmm I don't see this error on my editor.

Comment: Can you run you .ts file using tsc and any error?

Comment: @MBB I'm not writing native ts code, I'm writing a js file and annotating it with a d.ts file